# When describing living space/floor space, how should I read/say NxZ meters?

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I want to say something like: "This room is 6 x 5 meters" What word should I use to read the "x" between the two numbers? In Russian it would be "на", and in French "sur". Translating these words literally into English, it would be "on", i.e. something like "6 on 5 meters". Is it correct to say "This room is 6 on 5 meters" describing living space/floor space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use preposition "by"**

> [Used for giving the size of an area, object, or space by stating its length, width, height, etc.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/by)
>
> - The house has a spacious dining room, measuring 18 by 15 feet.
> - I usually get 4 by 6 inch prints of my pictures.
>
> Exceptional apartment for sale. This is a real 4 bedroom apartment with 3 baths.... A twenty ft by forty ft pool and recreational area...

Answer (score 5):

*×* is read as *by*, e.g.,

> 6 by 5 meters

You can easily remember it if you consider it a multiplication (and certainly it is, since we talk about the area).